# send an array of objects from one class to another

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have two classes:

```
FirstClass{
    private int id;
    private SecondClass[] arrayofSecond;
    private int ind;
    public FirstClass(){}
    public FirstClass(int id){
         this.id=id;
    }
    public void addElements(SecondClass e){
         arrayofSecond[ind]=e;
         ind++;
    } 
    public SecondClass[] getArraySecondClass(){
        return arrayofSecond;
    }    
}

SecondClass{
    private int id;
    private SecondClass(){}
    private SecondClass(int id){
          this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
          return id;
    }
}
```

Now I need to get the array that has been filled in the FirtsClass in the Main program, like this:

```
FirstClass f1=new FirstClass(10);
SecondClass s1=new SecondClass(10);
SecondClass s2=new SeconClass(20);
f1.addElements(s1);
f1.addElements(s2);
FirstClass f=null;
SecondClass s[];
s=f.getArraySecondClass();
for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    System.out.println(s[i].getId());
}
```

The problem is that I get an error of Null pointer exception. I have read that maybe this is not a correct way to do this by the principle of "not talk to strangers", but I do not see another way to make this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a `f` variable when you already have `f1`?

```
FirstClass f1=new FirstClass(10);
SecondClass s1=new SecondClass(10);
SecondClass s2=new SeconClass(20);
f1.addElements(s1);
f1.addElements(s2);

SecondClass s[];
s=f1.getArraySecondClass();
for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    System.out.println(s[i].getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to initialize the `arrayofSecond`.

In the constructor of `FirstClass` you'll have to do `arrayofSecond = new SecondClass[10];` or any other length you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirstClass f=null;
```

should be

```
FirstClass f= new FirstClass(10);
```

`f` is set to `null` so you are getting `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate the arrayOfSecond variable to avoid NullPointerException.

change  `private SecondClass[] arrayofSecond;`
to e.g.

```
    private SecondClass[] arrayofSecond = new SecondClass[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never allow outer classes to access your private data fields directly. So instead of

```
public SecondClass[] getArraySecondClass(){
    return arrayofSecond;
}
```

you should do something like

```
public SecondClass[] getArraySecondClass(){
    return (SecondClass[])arrayofSecond.clone();
}
```

Besides that, you need to initialize arrayOfSecond in FirstClass constructor and

```
f.getArraySecondClass();
```

isnt't the best idea when f is null.